# Cakephp 3.0 bulk insert

Tags: cakephp

In Cakephp 3.0, to **save many records**, it is instructed to use the `saveMany` function.

https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/saving-data.html#saving-multiple-entities

However, the above submit insert statement **one by one**.

I need to updated a few thousand of records at once, so I would like to **batch insert my records** instead of insert it one by one.

To verified this I tried `saveMany` behavior I inspected my `querys.log` it appears that using `saveMany` does not insert my query at a batch, and indeed insert it one by one.

In other word, I would like to have this:

```
INSERT INTO mytable (id, code) VALUES ('123', 'code_a'), ('123', 'code_b'), ('123', 'code_c'), ('123', 'code_d'), ('123', 'code_e');
```

But instead the following was executed

```
INSERT INTO mytable (id, code) VALUES ('123', 'code_a')
INSERT INTO mytable (id, code) VALUES ('123', 'code_b')
INSERT INTO mytable (id, code) VALUES ('123', 'code_c')
INSERT INTO mytable (id, code) VALUES ('123', 'code_d')
INSERT INTO mytable (id, code) VALUES ('123', 'code_e')
```

So my question is, how can I do **bulk insert** in **Cakephp 3.0**

Note: I do some research and see that a `saveAll` function was in **Cakephp 2.0** and it can do batch processing (supposedly), but sadly such function is not present in 3.0.

Comment: **https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/query-builder.html#inserting-data**

Comment: FYI, The method in https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/query-builder.html#inserting-data  is also insert one by one, already tested. Thanks.

Comment: That's not correct, you can set multiple value sets as shown in the second example. That will generate a query that uses multiple data sets in the `VALUES` clause accordingly.

Comment: @ndm Oh man, you are right, your answer does work! My apologies for wrong testing before hand. Please submit an answer and I will accept it, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bulk inserts in cakephp are quite simple:

```
<?php 

$query = $this->MyModel->query(); 

foreach ($data as $row) {
    $query
        ->insert(['column1', 'column2'])
        ->values([
            'column1' => $row['value1'], 
            'column2' => $row['value2']
        ]);
}

$query->execute();
```

Comment: How can I get all ids to the corresponding insertion at once?

Answer (score 1):

```
$mytable = TableRegistry::getTableLocator()->get('ModelNameOfTable');

foreach ($myEntitys as $row)
{
    $record = $mytable->newEntity();

    foreach ($row as $column => $value)
    {
        $record->{$column} = $value;
    }

    if ($mytable->save($record))
    {
        $id = $record->id; // for checking if needed
    }
}
```

Something like this should do it.

Just reference: https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/saving-data.html

ALTHOUGH, if your table is quite complex and you will require a lot cross-referencing / field checking, creating your own custom SQL execution as you did, could easily be more suitable.

The ideal of using the ORM and Models is to keep code shareable across different database platforms (models). In your case, you are writing something to "transfer" data rather than share.

Comment: The key point that I want to achieve is make the SQL`INSERT INTO mytable (id, code) VALUES ('123', 'code_a'), ('123', 'code_b'), ('123', 'code_c'), ('123', 'code_d'), ('123', 'code_e');` which I highly doubt this method will solved it. However I will try it tmr when I have time, thanks!

Comment: `you are writing something to "transfer" data` Yes, that is exactly what my logic is doing. I need to get a lot of data from db, process, then insert them back to another db, validation is already done prior to mass insertion. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

- When you make "bulk" insert with `INSERT INTO mytable (id, code) VALUES ('123', 'code_a'), ('123', 'code_b'), ('123', 'code_c'), ('123', 'code_d'), ('123', 'code_e');` you send all insert data in one sql query without validation, but db itself in background insert one by one.
- In ORM your app first make data validation, then create sql query for current entity. Not big difference in speed.

Comment: Thank you for your input, but in my testing there is in fact big speed different, after I switch from using my answer below, my query speed up from `30s` to `5s`

Answer (score 0):

Because I really need bulk insert, I now need to use traditional execute to handle my query:

```
<?php
    $sql = "INSERT INTO mytable ";
    $binding = [];
    $insertSql = [];
    foreach($myEntitys as $i => $myEntity){
        $myEntityArray = $myEntity->toArray();
        $myEntityArrayKeys = array_keys($myEntityArray);

        if($i === 0){
            $sql .= "(";
            $sql .= implode(",", $myEntityArrayKeys);
            $sql .= ")";
        }

        $singleInsertSql = [];
        foreach($myEntityArrayKeys as $key) {
            $value = $myEntityArray[$key];
             $singleInsertSql[] = "?";
             $binding[] = $value;
        }
        $insertSql[] = "(" . implode(",", $singleInsertSql) . ")";
    }
    $sql .= " VALUES " . implode(",", $insertSql);

    $connection = ConnectionManager::get('default');
    $connection->execute($sql, $binding);
```

This do the job but is a very ugly, hopefully someone can post a more cake native method, thanks!